# The specified value does not conform to the required format

Tags: django, django-templates

I have this code snippet in `django` template

`<td><input type="datetime-local" id="tdId_{{i.0}}5" value="{{i.4|date:'Y-m-d H:i'}}"/></td>`

The console writes
`The specified value ... does not conform to the required format. ...`

Which mask should I use to match the required format of `datetime-local`?

Comment: Maybe you have not a datetime variable here `i.4`?

Comment: @Eugenij `i.4` is a datetime variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`datetime-local` accepte `ISO 8601` date format. accoring to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#date) you can use the Format character    `c` to convert a datetime object to an `ISO 8601 format`

```
<input type="datetime-local" id="tdId_{{i.0}}5" value="{{i.4|date:'c'}}"/>
```

Comment: And is it possible to hide microseconds in the widget?

Answer (score 1):

this solution is also working:

```
{{ i.4|date:'Y-m-d'}}T{{ i.4|time:'H:i:s' }}
```

So, the whole code be:

```
<input type="datetime-local" id="tdId_{{i.0}}5" value="{{ i.4|date:'Y-m-d'}}T{{ i.4|time:'H:i:s' }}"/>
```